# convert flat array into multidimensional array in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to convert a flat array into multidimensional array based on 'parent' and look a lot of examples and get good results but have 1 issue. I am missing last time of the array.

first i created an **flat array**

```
$service_arr = array();
foreach( $order_info[0]['service'] as $ordered_service ) {
    $s_id       = $ordered_service['id'];
    $s_name     = $ordered_service['name'];
    $s_qty      = $ordered_service['qty'];
    $s_price    = $ordered_service['price'];
    $s_parent   = gp_get_item_parent( $s_id ); // return parent_id of the element.

    $service_arr[] = array(
        'id' => $s_id,
        'name' => $s_name,
        'qty' => $s_qty,
        'price' => $s_price,
        'parent' => $s_parent
    );
}
```

and this return's a flat array

**Result:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 29
            [name] => Another Facial
            [qty] => 1
            [price] => 1800
            [parent] => 16
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 17
            [name] => Facial 1
            [qty] => 1
            [price] => 2000
            [parent] => 16
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 26
            [name] => Addon
            [qty] => 1
            [price] => 500
            [parent] => 17
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 39
            [name] => Another Addon
            [qty] => 1
            [price] => 150
            [parent] => 17
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 18
            [name] => Facial 2
            [qty] => 1
            [price] => 2000
            [parent] => 16
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [id] => 38
            [name] => Nice Facial
            [qty] => 1
            [price] => 3000
            [parent] => 16
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [id] => 21
            [name] => Massage 2
            [qty] => 1
            [price] => 6000
            [parent] => 14
        )

)
```

**Converting flat into multidimension array:**

```
function create_tree_array( &$list, &$output, $parent_id ) {

    if ( ! is_array( $list ) ) {
        return;
    }

    if ( ! is_array( $output ) ) {
        return;
    }

    foreach( $list as $i => $item ) {
        if ( $item['parent'] == $parent_id )  {
            $item['addon'] = array();
            create_tree_array( $list, $item['addon'], $item['id'] );
            $output[] = $item;
        }
    }

}
```

**And using this function like**

```
$services_tree = array();
create_tree_array( $service_arr, $services_tree, $service_arr[0]['parent'] );
```

> Its working but the issue is that its **missing last item of array**:

```
[6] => Array (
          [id] => 21
          [name] => Massage 2
          [qty] => 1
          [price] => 6000
          [parent] => 14
)
```

Comment: more specific this question, it will help us to answered that question

Comment: the question is .. that i have a flat array and i am converting flat array into multidimensional array, but the issue is when i am converting flat array into multi dimensional it is missing last item of the array.

Comment: if i count the **count( $service_arr )** its returns me 7, but when i **count( $services_tree )** it is returning 4 arrays instead of 5

Comment: Please add result from `var_export($service_arr);` for testing.

Comment: @camelsWriteInCamelCase I am not talking about testing, I am already using print_r or var_dump for debugging, my issue is that my last array is missing somehow

Comment: With example of the array it will be easier to test your script. Converting from var_dump to real PHP array is not something we want to waste time on.